# After installing git bash on my Windows machine, I was immediately presented with the following error after launching the application:

Tags: git-bash

I get this command not found on my git bash, how do I sort it out on Windows?

EMA`S PC@DESKTOP-BD9K6IS $MSYSTEM /`__git_ps1 `$ ls LICENSE.txt  ReleaseNotes.html  bin/  cmd/  dev/  etc/  git-bash.exe*  git-cmd.exe*  mingw64/  proc/  tmp/  unins000.dat  unins000.exe*  unins000.msg  usr/ bash: S: command not found bash: bad substitution: no closing "`" in `

I was expecting a normal Bash shell and command line interface

Answer (score 0):

Add Git to the environment in the system variables path

Something like this: `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` or wherever you installed it.

And also restart the system.

Then search Git Bash, it should come up in the search console.

[image]